# Unable to setup Vespa container on multiple instances

Tags: vespa

**I have two instances where I have to deploy Vespa on a docker container. One container will act as a config cluster, container cluster, and content cluster while the other will act as a container cluster and content cluster.**

host.xml file for the application looks like:

```
<hosts>
  <host name="vespa-master">
    <alias>admin0</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="vespa-searcher">
    <alias>searcher1</alias>
  </host>

</hosts>
```

services.xml for the application looks like:

```
<services version="1.0">
    <admin version="2.0">
        <adminserver hostalias="admin0"/>
        <configservers>
            <configserver hostalias="admin0"/>
        </configservers>
    </admin>

    <container id="container" version="1.0">
        <document-api />
        <search/>
        <nodes>
            <node hostalias="admin0"/>
            <node hostalias="searcher1"/>
        </nodes>
    </container>

    <content id="content" version="1.0">
        <documents>
            <!--version 1 docs starts-->
            <document type="document_name" mode="index" />
            <!--version 1 docs ends-->
        </documents>

        <redundancy>2</redundancy>
             <engine>
                 <proton>
                     <searchable-copies>1</searchable-copies>
                 </proton>
             </engine>

        <group name="top-group">
            <distribution partitions="*"/>
            <group name="group0" distribution-key="0">
                <node hostalias="admin0" distribution-key="0"/>
                <node hostalias="searcher1" distribution-key="1"/>
            </group>
        </group>
    </content>
</services>
```

I am using a docker swarm to make an overlay network connection between the two instances. The command for which looks something like this:

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --subnet=<IP>/24 vespa_conn --attachable
```

The command to create a container on the first instance that I had used is:

```
docker run --detach --hostname vespa-master --network=vespa_conn <other arguments> --env VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS=vespa-master vespaengine/vespa
```

and the command to create a container on the second instance is:

```
docker run --detach --hostname vespa-searcher --network=vespa_conn <other arguments> --env VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS=vespa-master vespaengine/vespa
```

The reference for these commands is from this [page](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/docker-containers-in-production.html).

And after creating and deploying my application the state of the node on the second container is not showing up.

```
vespa-get-cluster-state 

Cluster content:
content/distributor/0: up
content/distributor/1: down
content/storage/0: up
content/storage/1: down
```

The issue that I found was:

```
content/distributor/0: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
admin/cluster-controllers/0: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
admin/slobrok.0: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
admin/metrics/vespa-master: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
hosts/vespa-master/sentinel: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
hosts/vespa-master/logd: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
[generation not up-to-date ignored]
container/container.1: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
hosts/vespa-searcher/logd: Failed to fetch json: Connection error: socket write error
[generation not up-to-date ignored]
```

After some tries. I had fixed the problem by adding:
`'override VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS vespa-master' in /opt/vespa/conf/vespa/default-env.txt` file in the second container and then restarting the services.

***Is there any better way to do this, so that I don't have to manually update the default-env.txt file?***

Also, While I was adding the 'configserver' or 'services' at the end of the line of docker run command as specified in the [page](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/docker-containers-in-production.html) I was getting this error:

```
[2020-10-15 11:36:13.782540] 1935/8285 (vespa-model-inspect.config.frt.frtconnection) warning: Connection to tcp/localhost:19090 failed or timed out
[2020-10-15 11:36:13.782631] 1935/8285 (vespa-model-inspect.config.frt.frtconnection) warning: FRT Connection tcp/localhost:19090 suspended until 2020-10-15 11:36:23 GMT
[2020-10-15 11:36:13.782647] 1935/8285 (vespa-model-inspect.config.frt.frtconfigagent) info: Error response or no response from config server (key: name=model,namespace=cloud.config,configId=admin/model) (errcode=104, validresponse:0), trying again in 6000 milliseconds
```

***What will be the reason for this error, Am I doing something wrong here?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this working you should avoid having underscores in the network name, use the fully qualified name for the config server and name the containers to get DNS working.

**Create the network on a manager swarm host:**

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable vespa-net
```

**Start a Vespa container running both the config server and the services (no argument to the entrypoint):**

```
docker run --detach --name vespa-master --hostname vespa-master.vespa-net --network=vespa-net --env VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS=vespa-master.vespa-net vespaengine/vespa
```

**Start a Vespa container running only the services (services argument to entrypoint):**

```
docker run --detach --name vespa-searcher --hostname vespa-searcher.vespa-net --network=vespa-net --env VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS=vespa-master.vespa-net vespaengine/vespa services
```

**Then use the fully qualified names in the hosts.xml:**

```
<hosts>
  <host name="vespa-master.vespa-net">
    <alias>admin0</alias>
  </host>

  <host name="vespa-searcher.vespa-net">
    <alias>searcher1</alias>
  </host>

</hosts>
```

**By deploying your unmodified services.xml I get the following state:**

```
[root@vespa-master /]# vespa-get-cluster-state

Cluster content:
content/distributor/0: up
content/distributor/1: up
content/storage/0: up
content/storage/1: up
```

Comment: Thanks aressem. This solution worked like a charm. Also, if possible can you share any documentation regarding the fully qualified name of config servers.

Comment: This is just the full hostname of the configservers used in the VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS environment variable (https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/setting-vespa-variables.html). In this case the fully qualified hostname is `vespa-master.vespa-net`.